# Get the top 10 IPs from the last 5000 hits (Apache access.log)

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I'm trying to get the top 10 IPs from the last 5000 hits out of an Apache access.log file.

I have tried this one-liner :

```
tail -5000 example_access.log |awk '{print $1}'|sort |uniq -c|sort -rn |head -10
```

What I get from it is :

> 1465 128.74.162.38
>
> 1154 194.63.141.238
>
> 820 176.31.30.184
>
> 235 217.164.16.157
>
> 1413 54.38.137.26

But it doesn't work as expected because if I remove the head -5 and replace it with a less, I am able to see the whole listing and I have this line **"422 80.120.179.134"** (which should take the place of this one "235 217.164.16.157").

I am using this file : http://www.almhuette-raith.at/apache-log/access.log.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected sample outputs too in your posts, you could use dummy ip values too.

Comment: You can use this file : http://www.almhuette-raith.at/apache-log/access.log

Comment: command you've shown seems fine... apart from what you highlighted, `1413` should have been second entry..  so try to experiment with smaller sample and see if you can spot the issue..

Comment: nop as the 4th line should not even appear normally...

Comment: `tail -10 foo |tac|grep -oP -m5 '^[^ ]+' |tac`  ,replace 10 and 5 with your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU your question you need to get the TOP 10 IPs who are repeating numbers are greater then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file| sort -nrk2.1 | head -10
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP wanted to check last 5000 lines and get the highest counts of IPs first 10.

```
tail -5000 Input_file | awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  | sort -nrk2.1 | head -10
```

Comment: Sorry for my English but I am not sure to understand your answer. I just want to get the 10 IPs addresses that hit the most from the 5000 last entries of the access.log (IP address and number of hits).

Comment: @reike, please check my edit solution now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Perfect ! This is what is wanted to do ;)

Comment: Maybe mention that you could get rid of the sort and head if you use the gnu extension `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat access.log | grep '\- \-' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

**output**

- 151 103.170.153.35
- 66 216.244.66.243
- 28 66.249.70.200
- 28 66.249.70.199
- 24 8.208.10.94